# Best way to set a >24 hour countdown timer in Android?

Tags: android, timepicker

I am an Android newbie and recently completed my first app, in which users can set a time, up to 24 hours, to countdown from, and then, as they go, perform some pacing calculations based on the current elapsed time.  The app is based on the CountDownTimer and TimePickerDialog classes, and is based the examples from this site and others (thanks to all).

Here is my problem:  I've been asked if I can extend the countdown timer to 84 hours (for long distance cyclists).  The TimePickerDialog was really easy to use - is there a straightforward way to "extend" the class to allow selection of up to 84 hours?  Or should I just resign myself to tackling my own custom widget?

Answer (score 0):

TimePicker only allows selection up to 24 hours. You will have to make your own custom widget.